# Why is there a Star Trek reference in the Zelda symphony?

Tags: soundtrack, videogame-soundtrack

In ["Ballad of the Wind Fish - Legend of Zelda Symphony of the Goddesses"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6T5n8zSbX0&feature=youtu.be&t=3m47s) at 3:47 we randomly hear the [main theme from *Star Trek*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWSp5ijOOfk) for just a short moment. Why? Why is there a *Star Trek* reference in the Zelda symphony?

Comment: Cross-posting the same question to two separate SE's is discouraged.  It should probably either be closed there or here.

Comment: @ChrisSunami It's discouraged, but not prohibited. I asked on SFF because I'm more likely to get an answer from avid, knowledgeable fans there, whereas MusicFans.SE tends to be more casual fans. The answer here on MusicFans.SE only found the evidence I was looking for once I'd asked on SFF. I only hesitate to delete this one because I don't want BCdotWEB to loose any rep. But now I know for next time. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably [a joke by arranger Chad Seiter](http://www.san-francisco-theater.com/theaters/davies-symphony-hall/the-legend-of-zelda-symphony-of-the-goddesses.php), who also worked on the music for the 2009 *Star Trek* movie.

> Jason Michael Paul and Nintendo proudly present "The Legend of Zelda:
>   Symphony of the Goddesses", a concert event that will take audiences
>   of all ages on a thrilling orchestral adventure through one of the
>   video game industry's most beloved franchises.
>
> Conducted by Eimear Noone, "The Legend of Zelda: Symphony of the
>   Goddesses" is the first ever video game themed concert to feature a
>   complete 4-movement symphony, **arranged by Zelda Symphony music
>   director Chad Seiter (*Star Trek*, *LOST* and *Fringe*)**, showcasing the
>   enduring and ever-adored work of Nintendo composer and sound director
>   Koji Kondo and his dedicated music team.

[An answer on another SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121422/31029) explains that [it is an easter egg](https://twitter.com/ChadSeiter/status/706902565867298816):

> Chad Seiter (‏@ChadSeiter)
>
> @jonkroupa HAHA yes! Good catch - yes **it was exactly that, an easter
>   egg to my Star Trek game score**. You are the first person to notice!